ARM Cortex-M PC and SP values - reset behavior
I am trying to understand the ARM cortex-M hardware behavior on reset; particularly how the SP and PC values are written upon a cold start or hard reset.
Basically, it would seem the hardware (aka PE or Processing Element as referred to by the Arm v7 Architecture Reference Manual) is doing this somehow. The first word of the vector table at 0x0 is taken for SP initialization and the next word gives the address of the reset vector which is loaded to the PC, and a branch to that address is performed to run whatever the reset vector does to continue the booting process. However I'm curious 'how' this is actually being done by the hardware.
From the Arm v7-M Architecture Ref Manual, Section "B1.5.5 Reset Behavior" describes actions taken upon reset through a pseudocode (truncated here just to focus on the actions specific to the question):
// TakeReset()
// ============
TakeReset()
   ..
   ..
   ..
   bits(32) vectortable = VTOR<31:7>:'0000000';
   SP_main = MemA_with_priv[vectortable, 4, AccType_VECTABLE] AND 0xFFFFFFFC<31:0>;
   SP_process = ((bits(30) UNKNOWN):'00');
   LR = 0xFFFFFFFF<31:0>; /* preset to an illegal exception return value */
   tmp = MemA_with_priv[vectortable+4, 4, AccType_VECTABLE];
   ...
   ...
   BranchTo(tmp AND 0xFFFFFFFE<31:0>); /* address of reset service routine */

Ignoring the rest of the actions (setting all registers to their reset defaults etc.) how are the actions of setting SP_main and the BranchTo() to reset service routine actually performed? I know this may be 'implementation defined' but how might they be implemented:

Are they hardcoded instructions somewhere in the on-chip ROM area so that the PC upon reset has the address of the instruction to read address 0x0 and load the SP and then load the PC and jump to the reset routine? (In addition to rest of the actions given in the TakeReset() pseudocode)
Is there hardwired logic to do these two initial steps such that these steps are being done before the processor begins it's fetch and execute phase. It would seem more efficient for the reset state of the core to be tied to the appropriate instructions, rather than implementing additional logic to perform these actions.

P.S.
A quick search here did find a few similar questions that provide some answers, but didn't find one that specifically answers the question asked here..
ARM Cortex-m4 boot sequence
What is the booting process for ARM?
On reset what happens in embedded system?
Where to find the intended boot sequence of an MCU

The SP is useless and no one ever uses it.  The first thing the reset code does is set the SP.  The first line VTOR<31:7>:'0000000 is saying that whatever the default 'VTOR' is, is used as the vector table.  So, some systems may have flash mapped at address 0xfe000000 and another at 0xeb100000.  The SOC designer will set 'VTOR' to the boot device.  It is even possible that VTOR maybe initialized base on pull-up/down through various means to allow different boot devices.

For many system the SOC vendor has on-chip ROM and control is handed to this code.  So for an end-user, the ARM reference manuals may not apply to the context of your question.  You should really take any SOC documentation as authoritative, unless you are RE the SOC ROM code.  Note: the 'VTOR' pseudo-code is HDL-like and a 0 is a single bit. <31:7> is a range of bits (from VTOR) and the bits are 'zero base indexed'.  On a software reset, the VTOR is retained (afair), allowing some double fault recovery.  Please research this; that is just a recollection and could be for some older ARM cpus.

We see (part of) this question from time to time.  The logic does not require instructions that go through a processor in order to perform operations like reading from addresses to find vectors in a vector table.  It is the other way around the logic has fundamental operations it can do that the processor when enabled and operating can use, but the logic can perform these with or without the processor running.  Like reading the vector table.

VTOR is not supported on all cores/implementations, including those with that register, as documented (for some).  For armv7-m I would assume yes.  What you cannot see is what the chip vendor gets as indicated by artless noise above.  There are what I was taught to call straps.  Note the documentation you can find does not have a reset value for the upper bits of the vtor because the chip vendor controls those with straps which could be hardwired or could be controlled in any way the vendor wishes including external pins like ST uses  for example to pick the reset boot path.

IMO it does not make sense to create additional instructions, get into more chicken and egg problems to have a slower instruction based process do a single bus cycle to read the first few words of the vector table.Reading the vector table is a fundamental logic requirement for a design like this with interrupts.Think of an interrupt, does it make sense to halt the core, somehow save state of the whole thing so you can execute a few instructions to cause a jump to an address, put it all back, then continue.Or just have a state machine of the tons you already have,do the two or three bus cycles?

It makes more sense to do this in logic.  Assume that all flip flops have a reset value.  These are described in the documentation.  There is no additional logic really required for this.
Creating extra memories and extra busses to have chunks of code, having to spin up the processor put it in a known state, save state in the case of an interrupt, restore state, then execute the interrupt while trying to have a very low latency.  The chicken and egg of it does not make sense to try to do with instructions.
Fundamental things like read and write bus cycles are state machines that the processor uses when executing instructions.  These fundamental state machines as well as others as needed are the core of a design.
A post reset state that takes the registers/flops as reset and performs a 2 or perhaps more bus transaction at VTOR, loads a couple of registers (another fundamental state machine the processor uses) is simple and does not add a noticeable amount of logic.
NOW....it is possible, and we can figure this out.  For example the STM32s have boot pins and/or internal non-volatile boot bits in registers, it is possible that the chip actually, always, boots the factory bootloader and that code then examines boot pins and fakes a sram or user flash boot.  But from the ARM perspective (arm is just one ip vendor among many for a chip company) they would strap the core in such a way as to do this, they would still have a mux to point address zero, the factory bootloader could do that.  I am just making wild conspiracy theories though it would not make sense to do it that way either IMO, just control the muxes from these few signals, that from a simple gate or few can come from different sources.
In documentation we do not have access to or if we do, the NDA says we cannot say we do (I actually do not), will describe the boot process from a wrapper around the core perspective.  For example the upper VTOR bits, last time I looked do not have a reset value.  And that makes sense because you would want the chip vendor having control over those.  Assuming this is true and the documentation makes this feel true, then that would imply that the boot process is as described in the documentation we have.  You start the clocks you set up your straps, you pop the reset(s) in the documented order, and the core logic then does a bus cycle at the vtor address, you answer and then if the address in the second word conforms to the rules (within a certain address space and lower bit set) then the cortex-m core starts execution.
Likewise when an interrupt occurs if it were more efficient to have instructions save state then there would be like the old days where your interrupt service routine saved state and not the processor.  For the cortex-ms the processor does which implies that logic not instructions gathers the several items documented and does one or a few bus cycles to save them on the stack, does another cycle to get the vector, and like a reset exception, sets the internal program counter register that affects fetching (an ISA like all of ARM's have multiple program counters not just the one in a real or fake register) and releases the processor to execute that path.  Certainly more obvious on the return from interrupt that the logic is triggered on a branch with a certain address pattern to stop the core, do some bus cycles, jam registers, and release the processor at the return address.

I think the Cortex-M interrupt behaviour is a good analogue.
